# Is it wrong to say "every line has ten trees"?

Tags: word-usage

Is it wrong to say "every line has ten trees"?
Should I use "each" instead of "every" ?

Comment: Both are fine.  There is nothing wrong with "every".  There is at most a nuance.  "Each" is a little more of a focus on each individual line, while "every" means each line, but refers to them more as a collection of  individual lines; a little more of an added focus on the fact that there is more than one.

Comment: I suppose you mean "a *row* of trees".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct if what you mean is

> every *(single)* line has ten trees

which is how it would be understood, "every single" is idiomatically equivalent to "all" or

> *all* the lines have ten trees

which would have the same understanding as

> *each* line *(of trees)* has ten trees

sometimes

> *each and every* line has ten trees.

gets used for clarity and emphasis but a slightly verbose.